# NullPointerException when setText to EditText - onDateSet

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment, android-datepicker

I have an editText, where when the user clicks it, a date Dialog appears, and when date is set, the date should appear in the editText field. Although simple enough, I can 't find why I get a nullPointer Exception. I have tried several ways and changed my code a lot, but nothing works.
Here it is one of the concepts of my code:

Start class:

```
public class Start extends FragmentActivity {

int year;
int month;
int day;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDepDate);
    editText.setText("date");

}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePick();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datepicker");

}

}
```

DatePick Class:

```
 public class DatePick extends DialogFragment implements
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
EditText editText;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etDepDate);
    editText.setText(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
}

@Override
public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.show(manager, tag);
}
}
```

also XML:

```
 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/etDepDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:hint="@string/dhint"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

I had made it work with another method, but it is deprecated and I don 't want to use it. DialogFragments seems the right way to do it.

EDIT:

```
 11-14 20:38:06.368: E/AndroidRuntime(31557): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 11-14 20:38:06.368: E/AndroidRuntime(31557): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-14 20:38:06.368: E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at        com.xxx.mytrips.DatePick.onDateSet(DatePick.java:36)
11-14 20:38:06.368: E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at     android.app.DatePickerDialog.tryNotifyDateSet(DatePickerDialog.java:148)
11-14 20:38:06.368: E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onClick(DatePickerDialog.java:116)
11-14 20:38:06.368: E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
11-14 20:38:06.368: E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-14 20:38:06.368: E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-14 20:38:06.368: E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-14 20:38:06.368: E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 20:38:06.368: E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-14 20:38:06.368: E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-14 20:38:06.368: E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-14 20:38:06.368: E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: Add a stack trace and/or specify the line in your code.

Comment: are you sure in the second case the EditText also has id `etDepDate`?

Comment: Hi BabyGorilla, where do you get NullPointerException exactly? Show us your logcat...

Comment: edit text is null for you.

Comment: I edited my first post.

Comment: Sometimes you get this error just because you are using wrong `EditText` ID, I was doing the same by mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you're using `editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etDepDate);`. findViewById returns null in this case because editText is not a child of the DatePicker view.

If the editText is part of the content view of your activity you can use this :

`editText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.etDepDate);`

This is not really good practice by the way. Preferably you would pass an external OnDateSetListener to the fragment.

Comment: wow, this worked!! Although know I have to work in the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
    editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etDepDate);
```

is giving you error as you can't find your `EditText` in `DatePicker`. You will need to pass your `EditText` in the constructor for `DatePick` or somehow pass the value back to it in its orignal `Activity`

Answer (score 1):

Create a constructor for you DatePicker class and pass the EditText to it. 
For example:

```
public DatePickerFragment (EditText editText) {
    this.editText = editText;
}
```

and then simply use it in `onDateSet()` method.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead
 - This fragment should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments) 
  (com.xxx.mytrips.DatePick)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
editText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.etDepDate);
```

instead of

```
editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etDepDate);
```

Because, you don't have edittext in your DatePick dialog.. Because of this only findViewById() returning null..

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove view from this function?

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    //so instead of:
    //editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etDepDate);
    //use this:
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDepDate);
    editText.setText(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
}
```

Comment: The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type DatePick

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `EditText` inside `DatePick` class. You need to send the text back to `Start` from `DatePick` class.
you can do it this way.

1. Define an interface and callback method in `DatePick` class.

   ```
   callbackListener listener;

   interface callbackListener {
   public void setText(String text);
   }
   ```
2. Implement the interface in `Start` class.

   ```
   class Start extends FragmentActivity implements DatePick.callbackListener {

   .....

   @Override
   public void setText(String text) {

   EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etDepDate);
   editText.setText(text);
   ```

   }
3. In `onAttach` method of `DatePick` class assign the original activity to the interface object.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
       super.onAttach(activity);
       listener = (callbackListener) activity;
   }
   ```

4.Call the callback method in `onDateSet` method and pass the text

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    listener.setText(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your Edittext is in Fragment Activity and not in the DatePicker DialogFragment You cannot access it directly in this way. Try creating a reference to your fragment activity and access it through a method. Declare Edittext's scope to be accessed across in this activity. Then,

```
public void setDate(String Dte){
  editText.setText(Dte);
}
```

And just reconstruct your DialogFragment onDateSet method like this.

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
 // Do something with the date chosen by the user
 ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setDate(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
}
```

Comment: You can do it using interface also.